# Python: file with programmer-defined attributes

Tags: python, file, subclassing

Using Python 2.5, I'd like to create a temporary file, but add (& modify) attributes of my own.  I've tried the following:

```
class  TempFileWithAttributes ( ) :
    __slots__   =   [   '_tempFile' ,  'Value'  ]
    def __init__ ( self ) :
        self._tempFile  =  tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        object.__setattr__ ( self, '_tempFile', tempfile.TemporaryFile() )
        object.__setattr__ ( self, 'Value', 123 )
    def __getattr__ ( self, name ) :
        if  name  ==  'Value' :
            object.__getattr__ ( self, 'Value' )
        elif  name  ==  '_tempFile' :
            return  getattr ( self._tempFile, name )
    def __setattr__ ( self, name, newValue ) :
        if name == 'Value' :
            object.__setattr__ ( self, 'Value', newValue )
        elif  name == '_tempFile' :
            setattr ( self._tempFile, newValue )

myFile  =  TempFileWithAttributes ( )
myFile.write ( 'Hello, Jayson!' )
print myFile.Value
myFile.Value  =  456
print myFile.Value
myFile.seek ( 0, os.SEEK_END )
print myFile.tell()
```

However, I am greeted with the following error messages:

```
object.__setattr__ ( self, '_tempFile', tempfile.TemporaryFile() )
TypeError: can't apply this __setattr__ to instance object
```

I've also tried subclassing `file`, but that wasn't working, either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you overriding `__setattr__` **at all**?!  You're not doing anything useful in your override -- and your override of `__getattr__` isn't being very helpful either.  I think what you want is rather something like:

```
>>> class  TempFileWithAttributes(object):
...   __slots__ = ['_tempFile', 'Value']
...   def __init__(self):
...     self._tempFile  =  tempfile.TemporaryFile()
...     self.Value = 123
...   def __getattr__(self, name):
...     return getattr(self._tempFile, name)
...
```

This does let the rest of your sample code work, presumably as intended.

Comment: Essentially the exact code I was a couple seconds away from posting. Curse you Martelli! However `__slots__` is very likely unnecessary here, so I would just drop that.

Comment: Thank you very much, everyone, and especially you, Mr. Martelli.  Your solution worked for me straightaway!

Comment: @Jason, yep, `__slots__` only saves a few dozen bytes, likely irrelevant since it's unlikely that a program will have a huge number of objects of this class "alive" at the same time.

Comment: @JaysonFix, you're welcome, but do consider following Jason Orendorff's advice and just removing the `__slots__ =` line, it's not really buying you much (though it's not exactly _damaging_ you either, a basically-free simplification of the code's worth pursuing).

Comment: __slots__   assignment has been removed ... works great! Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2):

Python complains about `object.__setattr__ (self, 'Value', newValue )` because `self` is not an `object`.

What you need is to inherit from object:

```
class  TempFileWithAttributes(object):
```

In Python3 that happens by default, but in Python2 it does not.

Comment: I was having a similar issue and this is what I needed thanks

Answer (score 0):

First step: use `setattr()` instead of `object.__setattr__()`

Second step: Instead of `setattr(anobject, 'string', value)` just use `anobject.string = value`

Because your code makes no sense whatsoever. I can't even figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, it is. And I even tried it. Getting rid of all that nonsense `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` means it works.